# Consolidating multiple if ... print statements

Tags: python

We are supposed to make a scheduling program, where you input the day and the program returns your schedule. Each day has its own schedule (monday and wednesday share the same). I'm only 2 weeks into this python course so we only know the basics. How can I boil this down to less code?

My professor told me to combine all these if statements to use one print function instead of seven. I shortened it by defining the days before the if statements, but I can't figure out how to get it down to one print command

```
 sunday = "Just talmud today"
 monWed = "Talmud \nComputing Theory"
 tuesday = "Talmud Klali \nIntro To Programming \nHistory \nEnglish Composition II"
 thursday = "Shiur \nIntro To Programming \nHistory \nEnglish Composition II"
 friday = "Lecture"
 saturday = "Get off the computer!"

 print("Welcome to your calendar")
 dayOfWeek = input("What day is it? ")
 dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek.lower()

if dayOfWeek == "sunday":
     print(sunday)

 elif dayOfWeek == "monday":
     print(monWed)

 elif dayOfWeek == "wednesday":
     print(monWed)

 elif dayOfWeek == "tuesday":
     print(tuesday)

 elif dayOfWeek == "thursday":
     print(thursday)

 elif dayOfWeek == "friday":
     print(friday)

 elif dayOfWeek == "saturday":
     print(saturday)

 else:
     print("Check your spelling and try again")
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: definitely use a dictionary

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to use a dictionary:

```
calendar = {
    'sunday': "Just talmud today",
    'monday': "Talmud \nComputing Theory",
    'tuesday': "Talmud Klali \nIntro To Programming \nHistory \nEnglish Composition II",
    'wednesday': "Talmud \nComputing Theory",
    'thursday': "Shiur \nIntro To Programming \nHistory \nEnglish Composition II",
    'friday': "Lecture",
    'saturday': "Get off the computer!"
}

print("Welcome to your calendar")
day = input("What day is it? ").lower()
result = calendar.get(day, "Check your spelling and try again")
print(result)
```

Comment: This is a homework assignment. When somebody is stuck, pointing him in the right direction is helpful. Doing the assignment for him is not.

Answer (score 1):

When the ifs are for simply mapping 1x1 values I like to use dicts

```
weekmap = dict(
  sunday=sunday,
  monday=monWed,
  wednesday=monWed,
  tuesday=tuesday,
  thursday=thursday,
  friday=friday,
  saturday=saturday)

print(weekmap.get(dayOfWeek, "else part"))
```

Comment: Nice -- The Op didn't have to do any thinking nor any work!

Answer (score 1):

### Use a `dict`:

- [Dictionaries in Python](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/)
- [Basic Data Types in Python](https://realpython.com/python-data-types/)

```py
day_response = {'sunday': 'Just talmud today',
                'monday': 'Talmud \nComputing Theory',
                'tuesday': 'Talmud Klali \nIntro To Programming \nHistory \nEnglish Composition II',
                'wednesday': 'Talmud \nComputing Theory',
                'thursday': 'Shiur \nIntro To Programming \nHistory \nEnglish Composition II',
                'friday': 'Lecture',
                'saturday': 'Get off the computer and do something my family would disapprove of!'}
```

### Create a function:

- [Python Functions Tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/functions-python-tutorial)
- This `schedule` function will continue to ask for input until a correct value is supplied.
- "combine all these if statements to use one print function instead of seven"

  - this function has one `print` for the seven days, as requested
- Note, `dayOfweek` was changed to `day_of_week` as per [PEP8: Function and Variable Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)
- [Python "while" Loops (Indefinite Iteration)](https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/)
- [Python Exceptions: An Introduction](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/)
- [Python KeyError Exceptions and How to Handle Them](https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/)

```py
def schedule():
    print('Welcome to your calendar')
    while True:
        day_of_week = input("What day is it? ").lower()
        try:
            print(day_response[day_of_week])
            break
        except KeyError:
            print('Check your spelling and try again')

schedule()
```

#### Output of `schedule()`:

```
Welcome to your calendar
What day is it?  daf
Check your spelling and try again
What day is it?  ad
Check your spelling and try again
What day is it?  saturday
Get off the computer and do something my family would disapprove of!
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps!

```
 sunday = "Just talmud today"
 monWed = "Talmud \nComputing Theory"
 tuesday = "Talmud Klali \nIntro To Programming \nHistory \nEnglish Composition II"
 thursday = "Shiur \nIntro To Programming \nHistory \nEnglish Composition II"
 friday = "Lecture"
 saturday = "Get off the computer!"

 print("Welcome to your calendar")
 dayOfWeek = input("What day is it? ")
 dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek.lower()

if dayOfWeek == "sunday":
     result = sunday

 elif dayOfWeek == "monday":
     result = monWed

 elif dayOfWeek == "wednesday":
     result = monWed

 elif dayOfWeek == "tuesday":
     result = tuesday

 elif dayOfWeek == "thursday":
     result = thursday

 elif dayOfWeek == "friday":
     result = friday

 elif dayOfWeek == "saturday":
     result = saturday

 else:
     result = "Check your spelling and try again"

 print(result)
```

To avoid `print` statements, you need to store the values in a temporary variable.

Comment: You can avoid the usage of a temporary variable by extracting the whole thing into a function, then using `return`s.